# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed [R studio ]

Tags: ssl, connection, rstudio

When I attempt to run the following code to connect to Amazon then store the information in doc, it shows below error message:

The code I use,
url <- paste0("https://www.amazon.com/dp/", prod_code)
doc <- read_html(url)

"Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
9.
open.connection(x, "rb")
8.
open(x, "rb")
7.
read_xml.connection(con, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = as_html, base_url = x, options = options)
6.
read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options)
5.
read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options)
4.
withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
3.
suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options))
2.
read_html.default(url)
1.
read_html(url)"

Does anyone encounter similar issue? thanks.